# Where do software and games place their registry keys?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

Simply put, where does software usually place their registry keys (I mean which folder of the registry in regedit)?

In every folder of registry there are many many sub-folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consistency in registry paths is awful.  Usually though, you're going to find what you're looking for under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE`, or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of places applications can write values to the registry.

A common, application-specific location though is

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software
```